# Sharepoint Lists to Word / Excel file

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

Is their anything in sharepoint to easily achieve this?

Say you have a list of 40 items, you can click a button to export all 40 items right to a word file or text file or something. Instead of having to open each item and click print.

I can do something custom wise, im just curious if there is a simple solution already implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Office 2007 installed and you visit a SharePoint list, you can just use the Actions > **Export to Excel** option (or **Export to Spreadsheet**). This generates a SharePoint Excel Query File that Excel can open up and pull the list.

Most Office apps, especially Excel, will talk to SharePoint lists in some form or another.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this already, provided you have MSOffice.

When viewing the list, hit the "actions" button at top and you should have "Export to Spreadsheet" available, this will drop the full list right into excel.